# Capturing the source or line number of uncaught exception in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, uncaught-exception

I've a node.js express app running in IIS. I found that the app is crashing frequently due to some uncaught exception. Hence I used process.on('uncaughtException') to restart the service in case of uncaught exception. I'm able to get the error as "ECONNRESET" but I'm unable to get where this actually happened. Is there any way to capture the error source or line number which caused the exception?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`process.on('uncaughtException'…`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) event which provides you with the Error object that contains the call stack

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: In my case, err object doesn't have stack attribute. It has only errno, code, syscall

Comment: This is the new error message 

{ [Error: read ECONNRESET]
 [stack]: [Getter/Setter],
 [arguments]: undefined,
 [type]: undefined,
 [message]: 'read ECONNRESET',
 code: 'ECONNRESET',
 errno: 'ECONNRESET',
 syscall: 'read' }